# TimeSpan.Parse microsecond and millisecond spans

Tags: c#, timespan

I am using a web service that return time spans in the following formats

- 300.43Âµs (microseconds)
- 212.675ms (milliseconds)

I want to be able to parse these to a `TimeSpan` object accurately. Currently I'm using `TimeSpan.Parse` but this fails on both occasions:

```
TimeSpan.Parse(json["time"].ToString());
// Exception: String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.
```

How can I parse these values?

Comment: What is the value of `json["time"].ToString()` exactly? I don't think it will parse `300.43Âµs` and `212.675ms` parts.

Comment: @SonerGönül: json["time"].ToString() == "300.43Âµs"

Comment: What's the deal with the `Â`?

Comment: @Chris - no idea, it's not my web service so I don't know why it's formatting the time spans like that

Comment: You could try using `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact` with a custom format, and then convert it back to a `TimeSpan` using `(x - DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)`. But I'm not sure if it's possible to parse fractions of micro/milliseconds like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to detect what do you have - microseconds or milliseconds. or just with simple check EndsWith

```
(\d*.\d*)Âµs // for microseconds
(\d*.\d*)ms  // for milliseconds
```

And @Chris already wrote - that timespan doesn't let you to parse microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the `TimeSpan` struct does not support parsing of units like that. You'll have to check and strip off the unit yourself.

For milliseconds then use [FromMilliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.frommilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx). For microseconds either rescale the value to ms (`FromMilliseconds` accepts a double) or use [FromTicks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromticks(v=vs.110).aspx) where each tick is 100 ns.